# Dataframe: Row(r) function?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm reading the official Spark [examples](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html) and using Pyspark.  I'm getting an error `NameError: name 'Row' is not defined` with the following code.  Is there some external import required for this function?

```
df = textFile.map(lambda r: Row(r)).collect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add import `Row` from `pyspark.sql` library to your code.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
```